# jQuery Appending html to div dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, api, cordova

Happy Pre Thanksgiving to all.

I ran into an issue while building a dynamic sliding gallery with jQuery + html and a Ajax call.

**The Issue:** When jQUery appends the generated `li` tags to the page, it adds and displays all of the images at once, If I add the `li` tags to the page myself everything works fine. My question: How can I append the `li` tags to the page dynamically as if I did it statically (Only one image displays at once, until the slider slides to the next).

Here's the situation:

I have a jQuery slider gallery that turns any `<li>` tags between the `slider` class into a slide, for example:

```
<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>Slide one</li>
    <li>Slide two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Instead of making the `<li>` tags static, I built a API in PHP that pulls the images from a DB and outputs the image links in Json format. Example below:

```
[{"pres_photo_link":"http://domain.com/myimage.jpg"},
{"pres_photo_link":"http://domain.com/myimage2.jpg"},
{"pres_photo_link":"http://domain.com/myimage3.jpg"}]
```

And I use jQuery + Ajax to create the `<li>` tags and add images between the `slider > ul` tags dynamically:

```
           $.ajax
            ({
                url: "My API URL", 
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "param=no",
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    for(var i =0;i < data.length;i++)
                    {       
                      var item = data[i];
                        var link =  "'"+item.photo_link+"'";
                      $('.wp_pres_slug').append('<li><a href="#" onClick="openInAppBrowserBlank('+link+');"><img src='+link+' alt="*"/></a></li>');
                  }
                }
            });
```

AND then `append` those elements to a `div` tag between the `ul` for the slider:

```
    <div class="slider">
      <ul>
         <div class="wp_pres_slug"></div>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**EDIT 1:** Here is a jSfiddle based on how it should be working, replace the `li` tags in the html with the `wp_pres_slug` class to see what it should not be doing. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mad3z8hs/1/)

Thanks in advance... I will keep researching and see if I can figure it out.

PS* the Ajax is a little rough, I usually clean up once I get everything working right :)

Comment: call $().slider() function after appending li

Comment: don't use a div, put the wp_pres_slug class in the ul and append the lis there

Comment: @Confused - I tried that yesterday and it did not work.

Comment: @jcesarmobile- I am in the process of trying that now.

Comment: @andre3wap can you add code of silder also

Comment: @Confused - here is a a jsfiddle with a working copy, edit the html on the fiddle to pull dynamically, in order to see what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/mad3z8hs/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the fiddle.

Please try with  `var link = item.photo_link instead of var link =  "'"+item.photo_link+"'";`
**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider">
<a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
<a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
<ul class="wp_pres_slug">
  <!--To pull dynamic, Replace the LI's with <div class="wp_pres_slug"></div>-->
    <li>Slide 1</li>
    <li>Slide 2</li>
</ul>  
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
var data =[{"photo_link":"http://img1.jurko.net/avatar_16844.gif"},
{"photo_link":"http://img1.jurko.net/avatar_16844.gif"},
{"photo_link":"http://img1.jurko.net/avatar_16844.gif"}];

for(var i =0;i < data.length;i++)
 {       
     var item = data[i];
     var link =  item.photo_link;
     console.log(link);
     $('.wp_pres_slug').append('<li><a href="#" onClick="openInAppBrowserBlank('+link+');"><img src='+link+' alt="*"/></a></li>');
 }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mad3z8hs/7

Comment: I would rather not have the `li` tags inside there, but for now that works. I added a `style=display:none` to the `li` and it still works 99%. thanks for the input.